# Does $G>0$ and $G' \le- cG$ imply that $\int_0^\infty G dt < \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, derivatives

Let $G:[0, \infty)\to [0,\infty)$ such that
$$\frac{d}{dt}G(t)\leq -cG(t),\quad\quad (1)$$
with $c>0$. 
Is it possible to conclude that
$$\int_0^\infty G(t)dt<\infty?\qquad \qquad (2)$$
I was thinking that from (1) I could get an inequality like 
$$G(t)\leq G(0)e^{-ct}$$
or something similar but I cannot apply Gronwall's inequality because the constant $-c<0$. Do you know how I could get (2)?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're using Gronwall's wrong. Lets just prove it directly. Set $g(t) = G(t)e^{ct}$. Then
$$ g'(t) = e^{ct}(G' + cG) \le 0$$
Thus $g$ is nonincreasing, i.e. $g(t)\le g(0)=G(0)$, so that 
$$ G(t) \le G(0)e^{-ct}.$$

Comment: PS: this is just the proof of (one version of) Gronwall's inequality. See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grönwall's_inequality for the statement; there is no restriction on the sign of $c$.

Answer (score 1):

Go like this.
$$
\frac{d}{dt} G(t) \le -cG(t)
\\
\frac{d}{dt} G(t) +cG(t) \le 0
$$
multiply by $e^{ct}$ noting that it is positive:
$$
e^{ct}\frac{d}{dt} G(t) +ce^{ct}G(t) \le 0
\\
\frac{d}{dt}\left( e^{ct}G(t)\right) \le 0
$$
Then we conclude: $e^{ct}G(t)$ is nonincreasing on $[0,\infty)$.  So
$$
e^{ct}G(t) \le e^{c0}G(0) = G(0)
\\
G(t) \le e^{-ct} G(0)
$$
This is enough to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Just to give a different approach, the assumption $G(t)\ge0$ for all $t\ge0$ implies

$$I(N)=\int_0^NG(t)\,dt$$

is an increasing function of N.  Now rewriting the inequality as $cG(t)\le-G'(t)$ we see that

$$cI(N)=\int_0^NcG(t)\,dt\le-\int_0^NG'(t)\,dt=G(0)-G(N)\le G(0)$$

hence $I(N)$ is bounded above (given that $c\gt0$). It follows that the limit

$$\int_0^\infty G(t)\,dt=\lim_{N\to\infty}I(N)$$

exists.